# Find constants such that the given functions are densities.

Tags: probability

A man sell broomsticks that come in boxes of 250 broomsticks each one, 50 of them a have length X and the rest of them length Y.
If $f_X(x) = ce^{-|x-50|}$ and $f_Y(y) = ke^{-|y-52|}$, find $k$ such that $f_X$ and $f_Y$ are density functions.

Here's what i have:
$\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f_X(x)dx = c\displaystyle\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-|x-50|}dx = c\displaystyle\frac{2e^{50}-1}{e^{50}}$, then $c=\displaystyle\frac{e^{50}}{2e^{50}-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let me help you. $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f_X(x)dx = c\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-|x-50|}dx = c\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-|x|}dx= 2c\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-x}dx=2c=1$. for $k$ you can do similarly. Is it enough ?

Comment: It is, thanks @Mahdi Khosravi. Now i see what i was doing wrong.